# How to trigger render on sort method in React (with filter and pagination)?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-hooks, pagination, filtering

This is my Sort.js styled component:

```
   <SortWrapper>
    <SortText>Sort By</SortText>
    <SortSelect onChange={onSelectChange}>
      <SortOption value="vehicleMake">Vehicle make</SortOption>
      <SortOption value="vehicleModel">Vehicle model</SortOption>
    </SortSelect>
  </SortWrapper>
```

This is function in App.js, where Sort component is rendered

```
<Sort onSelectChange={onSelectChange} />
```

This is a function:

```
  const onSelectChange = (e) => {
const value = e.target.value;

if (value === "VehicleMake")
  vehicles.sort((a, b) => a.vehicleMake.localeCompare(b.vehicleMake));
else if (value === "VehicleModel") {
  vehicles.sort((a, b) => a.vehicleModel.localeCompare(b.vehicleModel));
} else {
  vehicles.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
}
```

"vehicles" are a array of objects that I am getting from Firestore Database.

Whenever I change value of SortOption it does not sort my array of objects automatically, BUT it sorts it when I click page 2, and then page 1 in my pagination.

This is my Grid component:

```
       <Grid>
      {vehiclesData.map((vehicle) => (
        <VehicleCard
          id={vehicle.id}
          key={vehicle.id}
          ImageURL={vehicle.ImageURL}
          vehicleMake={vehicle.vehicleMake}
          vehicleModel={vehicle.vehicleModel}
          selectVehicle={() => setSelectedVehicle(vehicle)}
          deleteHandler={() => deleteHandler(vehicle.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </Grid>
```

This is my filter function:

```
const vehiclesData = useMemo(() => {
let computedVehicles = vehicles;

if (searchVehicle) {
  computedVehicles = computedVehicles.filter((vehicle) =>
    vehicle.vehicleMake.toLowerCase().includes(searchVehicle.toLowerCase())
  );
}

setTotalVehicles(computedVehicles.length);

return computedVehicles.slice(
  (currentPage - 1) * vehiclesPerPage,
  (currentPage - 1) * vehiclesPerPage + vehiclesPerPage
);
```

As I wrote before, I want my vehicles to render by make or model automatically, not when I click on page number in pagination.

Comment: did u check if the data is sortet over a console.log and only not rendered? i have on react multiple times the problem that the is changed are not triggered by objects and solve stuff like this over a a re-render prob aka setRerender(new Date()) which forces the re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sort method should look something like this

```
 const onSelectChange = (e) => {
let temVehicles = [...vehicles]
const value = e.target.value;

if (value === "VehicleMake")
  temVehicles .sort((a, b) => a.vehicleMake.localeCompare(b.vehicleMake));
else if (value === "VehicleModel") {
  temVehicles .sort((a, b) => a.vehicleModel.localeCompare(b.vehicleModel));
} else {
  temVehicles .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
}
setVehicles(temVehicles )}
```

And your filter function should look like this

```
const vehiclesData = useMemo(() => {
let computedVehicles = vehicles;

if (searchVehicle) {
  computedVehicles = computedVehicles.filter((vehicle) =>
    vehicle.vehicleMake.toLowerCase().includes(searchVehicle.toLowerCase())
  );
}

setTotalVehicles(computedVehicles.length);

return computedVehicles.slice(
  (currentPage - 1) * vehiclesPerPage,
  (currentPage - 1) * vehiclesPerPage + vehiclesPerPage
);},[vehicles])
```

Basically once onSelectChange runs, you update your vehicles state and then the usememo should run again and thus we add dependency vehicles to it

Comment: Using that variable with spread operator was key! Thanks man, appreciate your time for answering the question.